# Audio Stream by User Input

Tags: input, html5-audio, audio-streaming

How would I be able to set this up where the audio stream isn’t hard coded, and where a user would be able to input the stream themselves?

This is something I wanted to do, but haven't figured out how to do it.

**Code:**
https://jsfiddle.net/xnwr5jeq/6/

```
<audio controls>
 <source src="" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<div class="control">
  <label class="label">Stream</label>
  <input class="input" type="text" />
</div>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hPuh.png)

Comment: You mean, the source URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's make this a form.  Forms are the standard way to encapsulate a collection of input boxes.  They're well understood by normal browsers, but also by screen readers and what not.

```
<form>
  <label>
    Stream
    <input name="url" type="url" />
  </label>
</form>
```

This is similar to what you had, but I made a few changes:

- `<label>` elements need to either wrap what they're labeling, or the they need the `for` attribute.  Otherwise, they're not very useful.
- I dropped the `label` class.  You can style this in CSS without it by simply using `label` as the selector.
- I set a name for the `input` to make it easier to get its value later.
- The `input` is now of type `url`.  This has some [built-in validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/url), and will fall back to a regular `text` input if the browser doesn't support it.

Your `audio` element is fine, but let's re-work it a bit:

```
<audio src=""></audio>
```

Basically, since we're only getting a single URL from the user, there's no need for child `source` elements.  We also shouldn't set the `type` because we don't know what it's going to be.

Now, to directly answer your question... we handle the form submit with JavaScript.

```
// Ensure the page is loaded before querying for elements to attach handlers to
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
  // Get the form, add a submit handler
  document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    // Get the form values from the form that was just submitted
    const formData = new FormData(e.target);

    // Set the audio `src` attribute from the form's `url` field input value
    document.querySelector('audio').src = formData.get('url');

    // Prevent default form handling (which would reload the page, in this case)
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/xnwr5jeq/7/

Comment: I think you're missing this: type="submit"  value="Set"> Right???? https://jsfiddle.net/xnwr5jeq/16/

Comment: @MichelleSmith I was just pushing enter, but yes, you could add a submit button if you wanted.

Comment: How would I be able to get it to work with this code? https://jsfiddle.net/aohz8ns6/20/

Comment: @MichelleSmith How would you be able to get *what* to work with that code?  Post a new question with just the relevant code needed to reproduce the problem you're having.  You have a ton of extraneous code in that fiddle that you don't need.